# How can i randomize (NOT SHUFFLE) a string?

Tags: c#

So how can i randomize a string ? For example

Console.WriteLine(string);
I want it to write with 50/50 chance
String1, string2

Comment: In fact, given the sparse description (16 words only) it sounds like you do want  a shuffle some words with a fixed ending.  With Love, N.

Comment: You need to put more effort into this question, its completely unclear what you are asking

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear, I'm bad at english + unexperient at the site.. also , mjwills, that link answered my question TY! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Random` type to generate a random number between a min and max value.

```
string[] strings = new[] {"abc", "def"};

Random random = new Random();

int randomArrayPosition = random.Next(0, strings.Length);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(strings[randomArrayPosition]);
}
```

The above however isn't cryptographically random, it uses the system clock to provide a seed value, if you were to use this seed value when creating the `Random` class, the results would always be the same.